# How can an unsupported OS / kernel be imported to AWS EC2 as an AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to import virtual machines as AMIs that aren't specifically supported by AWS (see the list of supported systems [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html)). For example, Windows XP isn't explicitly supported, and attempting to import it as an AMI fails. The images are currently run locally on VMware Workstation. I am aware of the AWS VMWare integration, but I am unsure if it will accept these images. I have also considered ESXi on a base-metal instance, but there's no console, so I don't know how I would manage that, either.

Comment: One great thing about AWS is it's typically really easy to try it out. Import your VM, see if it works.

Comment: @Tim Yes, I can figure out if an image will work after about an hour each. But this won't help me if the image just isn't supported, and I need it in my environment. In this situation, I cannot just rebuild machines to a different AMI or attach my environment. I need these systems in AWS, however that may be achieved

Answer (score 1):

AWS have a list of the operating systems that can be imported using VM Import [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html). FreeBSD is not on the list. Whether it works or not, it's not supported.

Suggest if you must use FreeBSD you go with the Marketplace option MLu suggested.

My understanding is the only ways to create VMs on AWS are:

- AWS Import / Export Service
- AWS Marketplace

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have seen that link, and have it in the first sentence of my question. I'm not looking for a solution to FreeBSD, I'm looking for a general way to import images that are not supported. I see that FreeBSD is causing confusion, so I will edit my question.

Comment: Why would you want to run an unsupported operating system? AWS won't support it, reliability could be lower. As far as I know your only option to import VMs is the import / export service. You can try to import any VM you like and see if it will accept it.

Comment: In this situation, reliability is not my main concern. Yes, I can import images to see if they work. This does not solve the problem.

Comment: Based on what I know, the only way to import VMs is the import service. If it's not letting you import a VM I doubt it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to import existing images or is it ok to create new ones? For example FreeBSD is found on the marketplace:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/FreeBSD-FreeBSD-12/B07L6QV354

Comment: Import existing images. This answer does not solve the underlying problem, but I appreciate your time anyway.

Comment: @Pheric in that case be more specific in your question - make sure the question specifically mentions you want to *import existing VMs* rather than just *run* and tell us on what platform you’ve got them running now.